# Definite article omission: "The ones with *the* black hair" vs "The ones with black hair"

Tags: definite-article, prepositional-phrases

I wonder which phrase is grammatically correct.

> the ones with the black hair
>
> the ones with black hair

For me both sound right. But when I searched Google Books I found the second one to be far more common. But why was the article omitted? Does it have to do with the fact that this is a prepositional phrase or it's irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I hear is that
*"The ones with the black hair"*
indicates that the speaker **believes** that some of them **do** have black hair.

while
*"The ones with black hair."*
does not indicate the speaker **believes** some have black hair, but thinks some **might** believe so.  (Otherwise, why mention them at all).

However, the second form, without the definite article, could be used even if the speaker knows that some have black hair.

That means that using "the" adds information about the speakers belief, but its omission does not.

Comment: How does the second form have any uncertainty? Why would you say ‘the ones with black hair’ if some of them *might* have black hair? Correct me if I’m missing something,

Comment: To me, the first form indicates that the speaker knows that some of them have black hair. The second form, not having a definite article, does not indicate such knowledge, but it could have been used even if the speaker had such knowledge. That is how I see it. Did I express it badly?

Comment: Me too I don't understand why the one without 'the' implies any uncertainty, is this a grammatical rule?

Comment: I didn't say that the omission of the definite article implies uncertainty. I said the form _with_ a definite article suggests the speaker believes that some such exist; the form without does not suggest such a belief. That is not a grammatical rule, but the meaning of "definite" in definite article.

Comment: I guess my answer wasn't as clear as it should be. I'm going to edit it to add some emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

> But why was the article omitted?

If you use noun X to mean "type of/kind of/category of X", this is abstract and the article isn't used.

> the ones with the black hair

*Black hair* is no longer meant abstractly.  Furthermore, *the* means the speaker/writer expects you to know which black hair he/she is talking about, *and* the question of "which black hair" is important.

*Black hair* without *the* does tend to assume that all of the *ones* have hair.  If this isn't necessarily true, *the black hair* might be used, because that would create something other than the color to be distinctive enough for the question of "which hair" to matter.